# Bootstrap navbar changing places in google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The question is explained further down

Added Jsfiddle's instead of the code, you can't really see my issue there, which is weird. It's supposed to look like it does on the jsfiddles, but in Google Chrome 1 of the pages are more to the left than the other one.

I've got 1 page looking like this:
[fiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/zdqhqjar/2/)

And another one looking like this: 
    [fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/zaeunxt2/3/)

To me, these pages look exactly the same, and they should because i copied the first one and the only difference is some names on buttons beneath the nav-bar.

- One of the pages is more to the left than the other one in chrome ( the whole page )
- When I try it in internet explorer, the pages position is exactly the same, as it should be.
- When I'm opening the debugger in chrome, the pages also stay exactly the same ( instead of having 1 moving to the left.. ).

Why does it move when I'm using google chrome? Does anyone have a good solution to this? I want my pages to have the exact same position and looks.

I'm not sure why but, I have to add code to add links to jsfiddles, so here we go, this is where I think the problem is, but I'm not completely sure. :

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="en/home.php"><img src="image.png" border="0" align="texttop"></a>
                <a class="navbar-button" href=""><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" onClick="">Logout</button></a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="link">On boarding cases</a></li>
                    <li><a href="link">General cases</a></li>
                    <li><a href="link">Money laundry</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Check the borders of your tabs. It's likely that your active tab has a border and the others not. If that's the case, use a transparent border with the same width as the active tab has.

Comment: What do you mean by it is moving? Any screenshots would be better.

Comment: @DrCox You should firstly try any [CSS reset stylesheet](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) if you think it is only CSS issue

Comment: @DrCox Why don't you post jsFiddle replicating your issue then?!

Comment: Please post a JSFiddle so we can work out what it is!

Comment: @DrCox Ok but are you able to replicate issue on jsFiddle or not? I'm not sure to understand what you mean: `I've tried it in jsfiddle.net, and they look exactly the same without the CSS` Sounds like you aren't able to replicate it on jsFiddle, right?!

Comment: Why don't you try with CSS in jsfiddle and post link if replicating your isue? You have anyway to post MCVE so we can check isue, not just guessing. ..